# Error when trying to install Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, uefi, live-usb

I'm trying to set up dual boot with Ubuntu on my PC which already has Windows 10 installed. I'm following the steps in this guide: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/. So far I have created an Ubuntu USB install file using Universal USB Installer and the official Ubuntu 18.04 iso. I have shrunk my C: disk to make space to install Ubuntu. Now when I start my PC from USB and select "Install Ubuntu" I get the black screen in the picture below.

[image]

```
ACPI BIOS Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (2018123/psobject-221)
```

Comment: Seems a bios but https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9585671/

Comment: It needs to be made easier.  I am having problems despite being an IT pro.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Secure Boot in the UEFI setup utility and change SATA operation from RAID to AHCI. If that doesn't work try changing the other UEFI options suggested in the answers to [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/).

[image]

Comment: But how do you do that on a specific BIOS?  And is it really necessary?